# WordPress: Gutenberg not loading when Defer Parsing of JavaScript added in functions.php

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to incorporate a Defer Parsing of JavaScript function into my functions.php file. When I do, the site still works fine, but in wp-admin, anything involving Gutenberg wont' load and I just get the white screen of death. Any idea if this code is bad?

```
// Defer Parsing of Javascript
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
    return str_replace( ' src', ' defer src', $url );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page where you probably downloaded this code has a comment in it that solved it. Use this instead:

```
function defer_parsing_of_js( $url ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return $url; //don't break WP Admin
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
    if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
    return str_replace( ' src', ' defer src', $url );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 10 );
```

Source: https://kinsta.com/blog/defer-parsing-of-javascript/ (Answer by Dean)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, that actually threw an error right here as follows:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'src’' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /www/webroot/mysite/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/functions.php on line 548

That would be: return str_replace( ‘ src’, ‘ defer src’, $url );

Comment: Thats actually a very basic error type imo. It's when you forget a ; or ) or } or $ or something like that. In this case the quotes of the original article were of a weird type. I replaced them, can you try again with current code?

Comment: Yes, that made the difference. Thank you.